# How to automatically update tabular data or database

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm looking for an approach to handle updating some tabular data (i.e. txt or database) periodically (i.e. every one day). The GUI should access this data any time. I'm Ok with storing data in local host or in a server but for testing I will start with a local PC host. The naive approach is to update data every time the User open GUI. This works just fine but in the future, I need data to be updated automatically. What is the right approach for this issue?

Comment: What is changing?

Comment: @CandiedOrange, time.

Comment: Cute, but unless your logging time stamps you're trying to track something else. What?

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing data in a `.txt` file you can use `QFileSystemWatcher`, which emits `fileChanged` signal whenever that particular file is changed. Based on this signal you can update your GUI.

And, it should be possible for databases too.